# How to find O-Auth2 token for Play Integrity scope using googleapis?

Tags: google-api

I am trying to use Play Integrity in my project. I am unable to find auth2 token to use in Play Integrity API due to no scope for PlayIntegrity in googleapis.com. does someone used play integrity in their project? As official doc for the same is very less and concise,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library) (e.g. [java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-playintegrity/v1)) which already should support oauth2 token generation based on your service account credentials. If you want to obtain oauth2 manually, you can try [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l).